# Different size of a container when combing graphics and Sprite in a DisplayObjectContainer

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to make a grid of DisplayObjectContainers, so I am sorting elements depending on the width and height of each one. I add an Sprite in a container and the problem is when I add a Graphics element of the same size inside the container, the width and height changes. I narrowed the problem here :

```
var cont = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer();
stage.addChild(cont);
var convx = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('assets/img.png');
//>>>>>>> image is 289x333
cont.addChild(convx);

var msk = new PIXI.Graphics();
msk.beginFill(0x123456,0.5);
msk.drawRect(0,0,convx.width,convx.height/2);          
//>>>>>>> line above makes cont.width and height 309x343 (???)
msk.drawRect(10,0,convx.width-20,convx.height/2-10); 
//>>>>>>> line above makes cont.width and height = is 289x333 (same as the image)

cont.addChild(msk);
```

So why does the width and height changes when I draw a Rectangle of the same size in the same container ? Do you have the same problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of PIXI are you using? There have been dramatic changes in regards to width/height of a DisplayObject with release 1.6

Comment: Is cont added directly to the stage, or does it have a parent displayobjectcontainer?

Comment: thx for your help. I am on version 1.6.0 and yes cont is directly added to the stage. I can put more of the code if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I paste here an answer found on another forum. If it helps anyone...

PIXI.Graphics defines bounds like this:

```
var padding = this.boundsPadding;
this.bounds = new PIXI.Rectangle(minX - padding, minY - padding, (maxX - minX) + padding * 2, (maxY - minY) + padding * 2);
```

this.boundsPadding is set to 10 in the Graphics constructor.

I believe that is adding the extra 20px width and 10px height.

I set boundsPadding to 0 ans it worked perfectly !